# Binary vector expected value

Tags: neural-networks, probability-distribution

[Raul Rojas' Neural Networks A Systematic Introduction, section 8.2.1](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rojas/neural/chapter/K8.pdf#page=16) calculates the variance of the output of a hidden neuron.

Raul Rojas says that "for binary vectors we have $E[x_i^2] = \frac{1}{3}$" where $x_i$ is the input value transported through each edge to a node.

I don't quite get how he reaches this result.

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: The integral from 0 to 1 of x^2dx is 1/3, but isn't this related to a continuous random variable, instead of a binary one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some lines above the author says

> By the law of large numbers we can also assume that the total input to the node has a Gaussian distribution

hence we can assume $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ with the $X$ domain being **continuous**

Then he says the input vector is assumed to be binary which changes the domain **from continuous to discrete** so we can discretize it assuming $-1 \le X \le 1$ is mapped into zero and $X< -1 $ and $X > 1$ are mapped to 1

Finally according to the [68-95-99.7 Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) we can compute

$$ E(X^2) = P(X=1) \cdot 1^2 + P(X=0) \cdot 0^2 = 0.32 $$

Finally probably the author rounds this up to $\frac{1}{3} \simeq 0.33$