# Standard deviation of the total input to a neuron

Tags: neural-networks, math, probability-distribution

[Raul Rojas' Neural Networks A Systematic Introduction, section 8.2.1](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rojas/neural/chapter/K8.pdf#page=16) calculates the standard deviation of the output of a hidden neuron.

From:
$$
\sigma^2 = \sum^n_{i=0}E[w_i^2]E[x_i^2]
$$

When I try what I get is ([with $E[x_i^2] = \frac{1}{3}$](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/11971/binary-vector-expected-value) and $w_i \in [-\alpha, \alpha]$):

$$
\sigma^2 = \sum^n_{i=0}E[w_i^2]E[x_i^2]
= [n\frac{(\alpha-(-\alpha))^2}{12}][n\frac{1}{3}]=n^2\alpha^2\frac{1}{9}
$$

$$
\sigma = \sqrt{n^2\alpha^2\frac{1}{9}}=n\alpha\frac{1}{3}
$$

But Raul Rojas concludes:

$$
\sigma = \frac{1}{3}\sqrt{n}\alpha
$$

Am I missing some implicance of the law of large numbers use for the input to the node?

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If n different edges with associated weights $w_1, w_2, . . . , w_n$ point to this node, then after selecting weights
>   with uniform probability from the interval $[−α, α]$, the expected total input
>   to the node is $$\sum_iw_ix_i$$.
>   By the law of large numbers we can also assume that the total input to the node has a Gaussian distribution.

Note that the input to a node  is $$w_1x_1 + w_2x_2 + ... + w_nx_n $$

The variance of the total input to a node is:

$$\sigma^2 = \sum^n_{i=1}E[w_i^2]E[x_i^2] = n(E[w_1^2]E[x_1^2])
= n([\frac{(\alpha-(-\alpha))^2}{12}][\frac{1}{3}])=n\alpha^2\frac{1}{9}$$

since inputs and weights are uncorrelated.

I have taken out the summation and replaced it with $n$ times the variance of an input and a weight -- this can be done because both are [independent and identically distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables) in their own right and are independent of each other too. Variance of $w_1$ is the same as variance of $w_n$.

> Am I missing some implicance of the law of large numbers use for the input to the node?

Yes.

*Implication of Law of Large Numbers:*

Note that the *random variable* $E(w_ix_i)$ in  $$E(\sum^n_i(w_ix_i)^2)$$ is written as product of the random variables $E(w_i)$ and $E(x_i)$ $$\sum^n_{i=1}E[w_i^2]E[x_i^2]$$. This can only be written when the two random variables are independent. And the switching of expectation and summation is due to the [linearity of expectation property](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/).
How do we get independence here? LLN comes to the rescue.

That comes from the fact that -- according to the law of large numbers -- the *random variable* (total input) follows a normal distribution which implies the two random variables i.e. the weights and the inputs also follow normal distribution -- and [it is also given that the two random variables are uncorrelated and thus they are independent.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent)